# codeacademy python some questions about "range"

Tags: python, range

the question is：
On line 6, replace the ____ with a range() that returns a list containing [0, 1, 2].

the code is ：

```
def my_function(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print my_function(____) # Add your range between the parentheses!
```

My code is：`range（0,2,0.5)`，but it says it's wrong...

Comment: The function takes a single parameter, you know?

Comment: You need to pass a list to that function.?

Comment: You have misread the question; it's the call to `range` that should return `[0, 1, 2]`, then the call to `my_function` should return `[0, 2, 4]`.

Comment: Was your question answered? Or do you require further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

A range() that returns a list containing [0, 1, 2]...That would be: `range(3)`.

They're asking you to output [0,1,2] where the underscore is (line 6), not for [0,1,2] to be output by the function. It's a poorly-worded question.

So, simply, the answer is to put `range(3)` on line 6. This will cause the function to return [0, 2, 4].

Answer (score 0):

That exercise is poorly written. It would be impossible for the output of `my_function` to be [0, 1, 2] because you'd need a 0.5 in the input range. Still, it's unclear if that's what the problem is asking you to do. See the discussion [here](http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/535293c67c82cab69a00207e).

Answer (score 0):

Putting something inside of `my_range()` just replaces the"x" in `def my_fuction(x)`. When you out something inside the parenthesis, all it does is replace your arguments. If you `print` the calling, it won't let you call it again because you already assigned those variables.